# Why do both of these compile but only one of them runs?

Tags: f#, com, delegates

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
module PInvoke = 
    type EnumThreadDelegate= delegate of (IntPtr * IntPtr) -> bool
    type ComArrayList() =
        inherit System.Collections.ArrayList() 

    [<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
    extern [<return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool private EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);
    let getThreadWindows (threadId:int) : _ list = 
        let items = ResizeArray()
        let withData (hWnd:IntPtr, lParam:IntPtr) = 
            let _ = items.Add(hWnd,lParam)
            true
        let f = EnumThreadDelegate withData

        EnumThreadWindows (threadId, f, IntPtr.Zero) |> ignore<bool>
        items
        |> Seq.cast<IntPtr*IntPtr>
        |> List.ofSeq


let lp = Process.GetProcesses() |> Seq.filter(fun p -> p.ProcessName.StartsWith("L")) |> Seq.minBy(fun p -> p.StartTime) 
lp.Threads
|> Seq.cast<ProcessThread> 
|> Seq.map (fun t -> t.Id) 
|> Seq.map PInvoke.getThreadWindows
|> List.ofSeq
```

gives `System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Generic types cannot be marshaled`

but this one compiles and runs:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
module PInvoke = 
    type EnumThreadDelegate= delegate of IntPtr * IntPtr -> bool
    type ComArrayList() =
        inherit System.Collections.ArrayList() 

    [<DllImport("user32.dll")>]
    extern [<return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>] bool private EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);
    let getThreadWindows (threadId:int) : _ list = 
        let items = ResizeArray()
        let withData (hWnd:IntPtr) (lParam:IntPtr) = 
            let _ = items.Add(hWnd,lParam)
            true
        let f = EnumThreadDelegate withData

        EnumThreadWindows (threadId, f, IntPtr.Zero) |> ignore<bool>
        items
        |> Seq.cast<IntPtr*IntPtr>
        |> List.ofSeq


let lp = Process.GetProcesses() |> Seq.filter(fun p -> p.ProcessName.StartsWith("L")) |> Seq.minBy(fun p -> p.StartTime) 
lp.Threads
|> Seq.cast<ProcessThread> 
|> Seq.map (fun t -> t.Id) 
|> Seq.map PInvoke.getThreadWindows
|> List.ofSeq
```

why do both compile, but one gives an exception?

what's the difference between a `delegate of (IntPtr*IntPtr) -> bool` and `delegate of IntPtr*IntPtr->bool`? 
shouldn't they be the same thing? is `(IntPtr*IntPtr)` not the same as `IntPtr*IntPtr`?

Answer (score 4):

I think

```
delegate of (IntPtr*IntPtr) -> bool
```

is a one-argument delegate that takes a `Tuple<IntPtr,IntPtr>`, whereas

```
delegate of IntPtr*IntPtr -> bool
```

is a two-argument delegate that takes two `IntPtr`s as its two arguments.